# Can we delete old records from aspstatetempsessions table?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Recently I created `Session State` in my project, code is below

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" 
    sqlConnectionString="Data Source=ADMIN-9F8C57749\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
    Catalog=kecbliss;Integrated Security=True" timeout="60" 
    stateNetworkTimeout="60">
</sessionState>
```

The problem is day by day `aspstatetempsessions table` is becoming big
so my question is

1. Can i delete previous days records from aspstatetempsessions?
2. How to achieve this without affecting to project ?

**Project details**

   Front end `ASP.NET`
   Back end `MS SQL Server`

Comment: U don't need to delete the data .That is handled by `SQL agent`.Just make sure your `sql server agent` is running.Check out this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970788

Answer (score 10):

To resolve this issue:

**Step1:**

Make sure that the SQL Agent service is running and also check to see if the SQL Agent job called *SSPdatabaseName*_Job_DeleteExpiredSessions exists and run successfully.

If you have the SQL Agent Services is started and the SQL Agent Job is missing, proceed to the Step2

**Step2:**

Run the DeleteExpiredSessions Stored Procedure manually on the SSP database.

- Connect to the database server using Microsoft SSMS --> Client on
  New query.
- Make sure you have selected the SSP database in the new query
  windows.
- Type in “EXEC DeleteExpiredSessions” and execute the query.

This command would clean up the ASPStateTempSessions table and not remove any active connections.

Note: Depending on the ASPStateTempSessions  table size, it is recommended to run this command during off-peak times on the SharePoint/SQL server.

To register the job to be run automatically in the future follow the below steps:

- Ensure the SQL Agent is on (it should be set as an Automatic startup
  Windows service as well)
- Obtain the SSP database name that contains the ASPStateTempSessions
  table missing an associated SQL Agent Job.
- Execute the following command on a WFE or any application servers
  with the server farm:

From the command prompt get to the ASP .Net folder %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -sqlexportonly exportfilepath.sql -ssadd -sstype c -d SSP db name
```

- Open the exportfilepath.sql file in a note pad, make sure to select
  the text between the following lines:

/* Create the job to delete expired sessions */

and

/************************************************************/

- Copy the above copied test and Execute the code on the SQL box
  hosting the SSP database.

Now you should find a SQL Agent Job is created.

Raj

Source:  support.microsoft.com/kb/970788

Comment: ***Performance issues*** about `DeleteExpiredSessions`: https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/optimize-aspstate